# Where is the custom protocol mapper in Keycloak 20.0.2?

Tags: keycloak

I'm upgrading my Keycloak from 16 to 20.

In 16 I could use this screen to add a custom mapper.

[image]

In 20.0.2 I can't find this form in the admin panel. There is a `Client scopes` tab for each client, and it has an add button. But it does not allow me to define my custom mapper. I just adds predefined mappers.

Where is that form?
How can I add custom mapper to a client in Keycloak 20.0.2?

Comment: Just to mention that if you use terraform you don't need to rely on the UI anymore.
In keycloak they did not changed that much the api from version 16 to 20.

Check the doc and look for `_protocol_mapper` resources:

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/mrparkers/keycloak/latest/docs

The objects will be valid in most of the cases across versions.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

IMO the old ui was a bit more intuitive in this regard. With the new one you need to:

- Go to your Realm
- Go to Clients and click on your client
- switch to 'Client Scopes'

In the 'Assigned client scope' click on your client-id-dedicated:

[image]

then you go to the following menu:

[image]

Click on 'Configure a new Mapper' and then select 'User Attribute' and you get something as follow:

[image]

Comment: omfg what were they thinking putting it there? Thank you for your guide!